# Random and replacement characters in c++ output

Tags: c++, arrays, string, random

I am writing a program to reverse a string and insert random characters in between.
Here is my code:
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include "encrypter.cpp"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char message[256];
 this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
 cout <<    "Make sure theres no one around you" << endl;
 this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
 cout <<    "Enter secret message ";
 cin.get(message, 256);
 cout <<    "message encrypted" <<  endl;
 enc(message);
 return 0;
}
```

encrypter.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int getRandom(int a, int b) {
    return a + (rand() % static_cast<int>(b - a + 1));
}
using namespace std;
void enc(char message[256]) {
    int i = 0;
    int len =   strlen(message);
    int revlen =    len - 1;
    int wtpselector;
    int charselector;
    int encsim;
    char randchar[6] =  "@#$%&";
    char strreved[256];
    char strenc[1024];
    while (i <  len) {
        strreved[revlen]    =   message[i];
        i++;
        revlen--;
    }
    revlen =    strlen(strreved);
    len =   revlen - 1;
    i = 0;
    encsim =    0;
    while (i <  revlen) {
        wtpselector =   getRandom(0, 4);
        charselector =  getRandom(0, 4);
        if (wtpselector ==  0) {
            strenc[encsim]  =   strreved[i];
            i++;
            encsim++;
        } else {
            strenc[encsim]  =   randchar[charselector];
            encsim++;
        }
    }
    cout << strenc << endl;
}
```

But the output has many random characters that are not supposed to be there and are not in the program.
Like:

```
Input: hello world
```

```
Output: $%@$#&&d&&@%$%1%row &#$$@%&ol@%#@%&1%&#$&#ehe$%%€@@8@&%@$#& #%@@%&¢&@%#&#$#@$#%%##&%#@&#&$8%#$#@#$@$@#%&&@&#@Q#$$#&¢%@% Q#\#&$@#{&&&&$@¢ \ $$$$@@@@@#&&&%%&&%{ $@¢v#&@&~u@@@@%&%¢
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using `std::string` instead of char arrays? It'll make things much simpler.

Comment: You seems to have forgetting that `char` strings in C++ are really called ***null-tterminated** byte strings*.

Comment: Because this is a learning project about char arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed two important things:

- when you declare an array it's values are not defined (whatever is in memory)
- strlen counts to the first occurance of '\0' character

In order for your code to work you must initialize char arrays, which means change those two lines:

```
char strreved[256];
char strenc[1024];
```

to:

```
char strreved[256] = {0};
char strenc[1024] = {0};
```

Comment: what is the differrence between one having space and one not? Also will this fix the random character bug?

Comment: Space has nothing to do with it, only matter of style (i fixed it).